# Why is yarn is taking too long to install packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package, yarnpkg

It has been 1 hour since i ran `yarn add react-dnd react-dnd-html5-backend` and up to now the packages are not yet installed.
I have tried pressing enter / tab / space keys but no changes

[image]

Comment: network issues to some repository perhaps?

Comment: It happens to all packages I install